# LM239 Supply/Open Collector Output Voltage

Tags: comparator

I wish to power LM239 comparator from a +5V single supply and use the open-collector output to switch a 24V load (resistor plus LED). Is this permissible?

http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm239a.pdf

Comment: Yes, if you look at the datasheet schematic (Figure 6) you can see the output is a single NPN transistor capable of withstanding 36 V and sinking 20 mA.

Comment: And this supply voltage is completely separate from the other +5V supply. What about  supply sequencing?

Comment: +5 VCC should be up before the high voltage supply or else there is a chance of momentary high dissipation in the output transistor.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have an open collector, the voltage used at the collector is **independent** from Vcc.  Therefore, you can connect the collector to 24V supply, as long as you **limit the current** to 20ma max.  In calculating the max current, assume the transistor is a short, so your limiting resistor should not be less that 1.2K ohms.